# tentando me conectar com mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando conectar ao banco de dados via `myqli` com `php` mas não estou conseguindo. Segue o código:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>sistema de cadastro</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get" action="cadastramento.php">
    nome:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <p></p>
    sobre nome:
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" />
    <p></p>
    senha:
    <input type="password" name="senha" />
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Agora o código de conexão mysqli em php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> cadastramento</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'mydb';

$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $nome, $ssobrenome, $senha);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

?>

<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `titulo` FROM `cadastramento` LIMIT 5";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
  echo 'ID: ' . $dados['id'] . '';
  echo 'Título: ' . $dados['titulo'] . '';
}
echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows;

?>
```

Comment: Defina melhor sua pergunta, ajuda nas respostas, de inicio entendi sobre conectar o banco. e segue resposta.

Comment: Você precisa informar mais detalhes: ocorre algum erro ou nada acontece?

Comment: Você  não vai passar uma senha por `get` O.o

Answer (score 2):

Você está fazendo a conexão 2 vezes e a primeira está informando variáveis não declaradas no código. Altere e deixe desta forma:

```
<?php

$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'mydb';

$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
} else {

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `titulo` FROM `cadastramento` LIMIT 5";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($dados = $query->mysqli_fetch_array()) {
        echo 'ID: ' . $dados['id'] . '';
        echo 'Título: ' . $dados['titulo'] . '';
    }
    echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa passar os dados via post:

E o botão:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
```

Recomendo fazer passo a passo. Por exemplo:

verificar se conectou com o servidor de banco. Depois verificar se conectou com um determinado banco passado no parâmetro.

Se você fazer tudo, para corrigir os erros é mais complexo. Passo a passo, principalmente quando a gente não tem experiência, é melhor para resolver cada bug.